# I cannot import beautiful soup on python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-import

I installed Beautiful Soup library, and it seems to be well set up as there is the `bs4` folder in `C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages`.

(I changed the name into `bs4` before installation, and it went the same after install)

But when I type in `from bs4 import beautifulsoup` in the code, it says there is no such library.

And I don't see any `beautifulsoup.py` or something. Isn't there supposed to be one?

I'm really confused. Anyone help please?

Comment: Have you tried `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: does import bs4 give any error? Like alecxe said it's most like case mismatch.

Answer (score 24):

The module names are case sensitive.

Try

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: depends on how you want to use it, import bs4 would do too, but you will have to use bs4.BeautifulSoup() while making a soup object.

Comment: you can also use from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4. then you can use bs4() for creating object

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you give 'B' and 'S' as capital while typing 'BeautifulSoup'

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file in the same directory called `bs4.py`, This is the problem, don't name your files as package names, and btw package names are case-sensitive.